# Variational characterization of the first Steklov eigenvalue of an elliptic operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, linear-pde

Prove

Let
$I (u,v) = \langle u, \mathcal{L}v \rangle_{L^2 (\Sigma) } + \langle u , \mathcal{B} v \rangle_{L^2(\partial \Sigma)} $

then $\rho$ is  frist  eigenfunction of $\mathcal{I}$ if

\begin{align}
    \mathcal{I}( \rho, \phi) = \sigma_1 \langle \rho, \phi \rangle_{L^2 (\partial \Sigma) }
\end{align}
$\forall \phi \in  C^{\infty}( \Sigma )$.
This is equivalent to saying that

$\mathcal{L}\rho = 0$  $ \text{on}$    $  \Sigma $, $ \mathcal{B}\rho=\sigma_1 \rho $  $ \text{on }  \partial \Sigma,$

for $\mathcal{L} = \Delta + f $ and $\mathcal{B} = \partial_{\nu} + g$.  $f,g \in C^{\infty}(\Sigma)$

furthermore,

\begin{eqnarray}
\sigma_1 =\inf_{\phi \in  \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\Sigma) \setminus \{0\}}  \dfrac{\mathcal{I}(\phi, \phi)}{\int _{\partial \Sigma} \phi^2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.